# Uniform Cauchy sequence in Bloch space $\mathcal{B}$

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, sequence-of-function

> The Bloch space $\mathcal{B}$ consist of all analytic fuctions $f$ defined on the open unit disc $\mathbb{D}$ such that
> \begin{align}
> ||f||_\mathcal{B}:=\sup_{|z|<1}(1-|z|^2)|f'(z)|<\infty.
> \end{align}
> The Bloch norm is defined as $||f|| = ||f||_\mathcal{B} + |f(0)|$.

According to the book *Bergman Spaces* by P. Duren and A. Schuster (proposition 1, chapter 2.6) the following inequality is satisfied:
\begin{align}
|f(z)| \leq ||f|| \log \frac{1+|z|}{1-|z|}, \; \; \forall\; |z|\geq \frac{1}{2}.
\end{align}
Then, when they prove that $\mathcal{B}$ is complete, they say that if one has a Cauchy sequence $\{f_n\}$ in $\mathcal{B}$, then by the previous inequality it is a **uniform Cauchy sequence** on each compact subset of $\mathbb{D}$ and thus it is **uniformly convergent** in $\mathbb{D}$.

I do not understand how this inequality implies that the sequence is a uniform Cauchy sequence on each compact subset of $\mathbb{D}$.

The reason they give is:

> The inequality implies that the pointwise evaluation is a bounded linear functional on the Bloch space, with a norm that is uniformly bounded on each compact subset of $\mathbb{D}$. This, together with the maximum principle, implies that if a sequence of functions converges in the Bloch norm, then it does so locally uniformly.

But I do not follow all these conclusions. Could you explain me these consequences? I would appreciate it very much because I really want to understand this proof.

Comment: Note that any compact set $K$  in the unit disc is included in a disc of radius $r$ at least $1/2$ (and less than $1$of course) and the logarithmic  factor is uniformly bounded by some c_r on the closed disc of that radius, so if $||f_n-f_m|| \le \epsilon$ on the closed disc of radius $r$ then clearly $|f_n(z)-f_m(z)| \le c_r\epsilon$ on the closed disc (first on the circle of radius $r$ where the inequality  in the OP holds and then by maximum modulus on the disc) hence it is uniformly cauchy in modulus on the disc and so on $K$

Comment: "I do not understand how this inequality implies that the sequence is a uniform Cauchy sequence." I don't believe it is uniformly Cauchy. I also find it hard to believe that book says this. Do they actually say uniformly Cauchy, or is it "uniformly Cauchy on compact sets"???

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich No, they say it is a is a uniform Cauchy sequence on each compact subset of $\mathbb{D}$.